# Is one answer per country acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers

As I was commenting on a [question about international travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83913/using-us-chip-signature-credit-cards-abroad-in-chip-pin-countries), I mentioned to the OP that it would have been easier if he or she have had added country information (in the question or in the tags).

I then wondered if it would be acceptable to provide as many separate answers as there are countries - the rationale being that each answer could then be improved on its own, with its own comments etc.

---

It would have even be ideal to bootstrap the answers with empty answers (one per country) but this would not work with the current rep system where the person who started the answer is rewarded, as opposed to the one who provided the answer. In the vast, vast majority of the cases this is the same person but the bootstraping would be an edge case

Comment: Questions that call for one answer per country in the world are usually the kind of thing we close as "too broad." It's just not practical to collect information for that many countries and keep it up to date; this isn't wikpedia. Such a question also isn't "an actual problem" the OP has, as few users plan to visit all the countries in one trip.

Comment: @ZachLipton: the OP plans to visit (I assume) a few countries in Europe. From the answers and the comments each country will be different so it would have made sense to separate the countries in answers so that they can be edited independently (instead of having 5 answers, all overlapping). But OK, if the rule is not to do such a break down then fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. StackExchange encourages as many questions as possible so that it's easy to find a solution to the exact problem you're trying to solve on Google. Therefore OP would need to create a separate question for each country or a single answer would be created where all the countries are listed. A good example is [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/69630/9009).

Answer (score 1):

No - the same answer as @JonathanReez's but from a slightly different perspective. The *Question* would be off topic:

[too broad](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) *- if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format*

Similarly one of the reasons asking subjective questions should be avoided is:

[every answer is equally valid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)